# EPPLUS System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Worksheet position out of range

Tags: asp.net, excel, iis, visual, epplus

les expongo mi problema,

Tengo una web que accede a un fichero excel y actualiza unos datos sobre el excel, al probarlo sobre mi equipo con visual estudio funciona sin problemas, pero cuando publico en IIS al listar las pestañas del excel me da ese error, el archivo si lo abre pero es como si no pudiera leer el contenido, he mirado mil cosas por si fuera algo de permisos pero no he dado con ello. Alquien podría dar algo de luz a este problema.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.